# Static website note showing up on google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have followed the instructions given on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website, yet my domain name still lands on the page with this error:

> This site can’t be reached 
>   afrikincm.com’s server IP address could not be found.
>   Search Google for afrikincm
>   ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

My doamin registrar is goDaddy.com and  all i did there was:

[see godaddy dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QOcG.png)
All objects added to my bucket on Google Cloud Platform have been made public yet something still doesn't seem to be working right. 
I really will appreciate some help here guys.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that something is wrong and somewhere down the line and the DNS record is not resolving to the content of your gcs bucket.

First of all, be sure that the bucket name is exactly the value that you are specifying as CNAME.

Then review and re-take the steps suggested in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

1. Make sure that billing is enabled
2. Verify that you own and manage the domain that you'll be using: [webmaster central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en)
3. Create a CNAME record that points to c.storage.googleapis.com
4. Create a bucket whose name matches the CNAME you created for your domain
5. put files in your bucket (like an index.html)
6. make all object public with gsutil iam ch allUsers:objectViewer gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
7. setup index + error page with: gsutil web set -m index.html -e 404.html gs://[BUCKET_NAME]

Judging from the error, it seems that something is wrong with the godaddy records or the bucket name or the verification step :)